# Postgresql 9.5 performance when comparing date to string faster then when comparing date to date

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I'm evaluating a query performance and came to a curious finding....

I'm trying to get the count of items created today grouped by a column

Pretty simple SQL query:

```sql
SELECT 
  count(id), total_units_sold 
FROM public.items x
WHERE 
  created_at > current_date
GROUP BY total_units_sold ORDER BY 1 DESC;
```

The interesting finding is that when I run the same query using the current_date as the string `2023-04-18` the result is considerably faster;

To give some context on table size, there's `32.000` results in that query and the whole table have about `12.000.000` recods

Execution time when using `current_date`:

[image]

Execution time when using `2023-04-18`:

[image]

So the question here is:
Why does this happens?

Notes:

- The table is not indexed on `created_at` and I cannot change that on the moment
- Result of the EXPLAIN for both queries (Sorry for the hidden parts)

[image]

Result of the explain

Comment: Without an `EXPLAIN(analyze, buffers) <the_query>` there really no way to determine this.

Comment: To me both queries look rather slow, even 1.3 seconds is an eternity in my world. And like Adrian said, without a queryplan there is nothing to compare

Comment: As others have expressed, without the output from `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)...` any suggestions are just blind guesses. Having the table's DDL, including index details, would help, but the execution plan is still vital. Have comparable execution times been observed for multiple runs of each query? If not, then the difference might be due to database or system activity unrelated to the queries. I can confidently guess that there isn't an index on _created_at_.

Comment: Thanks for the responses guys, the table does not have an index on created_at indeed, and unfortunatelly I'm not in position to add it =/ _____

I did tried the queries a bunch of time and the result times are consistently close to the ones I posted
____
I'll update the question with the explain (analyze, buffers) result

Comment: Also, I cannot post the table DDL at the moment

Comment: The plans show that you are using an old version of Postgres. The problem with `current_date` was known and has been solved in Pg10 or 11 (can't remember exactly). Use `now()::date` instead or (better) upgrade to the latest version.

Comment: Are you sure that's the query? Unless you have conquered time travel, `created_at` should be in the *past*, so there should be no rows for which `created_at > current_date` is true. Also, is `created_at` a timestamp or a date type? If it's a timestamp, then your query may be converting every row to a date before comparing to match the types of the column with the query constant, so try `created_at > current_timestamp` instead.

Comment: @Bohemian time is correct =)

Comment: @klin thanks for the tip
It does performs better
Can you post your suggestion as an answer since it solves the doubt I had?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with `current_date` existed in older Postgres versions. Here is a discussion from eight years ago on [pgsql-performance.](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/30718.1447773997%40sss.pgh.pa.us)

The best option is to upgrade Postgres to the latest version. Alternatively, use `now()::date` instead of `current_date` as a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

Because `created_at` is a `timestamp` type, but `currrent_date` is a `date` type, postgres tends to coerce the column type to the constant value in the query before comparing. This means that *every* row is read from disk and the created_at value cast to a date, which is relatively expensive.

Instead, use `current_timestamp`, whose type is the same as the column:

```sql
where created_at > current_timestamp -- no casting required
```

If you have an index on `created_at`, it's a candidate for use when the types of the comparison match.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'll check the result with what you suggested